# Design for hierarchical content in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns, android-resources

Well I am new to android and it is my first app so thought I should take a simple project.
The app is a book. You see a list of titles and you select one then the text for that title appears.
I wanted the design to be in a way that when I add a new title I add its name at most at one place in the code.
My first idea was to have two activities. The "rootAct" shows the list and "title_viewAct" displays the article body. It could be done by "rootAct" telling which title was chosen to title_viewAct then title_viewAct could call setContentView() on the appropriate layout file.
The problem is this design is that rootAct cannot populate the list based on the layout XMLs alone. I couldn't find a way to populate the list in a correct manner by reading data from resources. Should I create an activity for each title instead of using one activity? Or I can create a global list of pairs of {entry_name,entry_resource_name} and populate the list with entry_names then title_viewAct can set the right layout to display.

Beside all these is there a place to use fragments here?

The question is what is the best design pattern for this app?

Answer (score 0):

The design pattern you can use is the adapter pattern. There are adapters built in to the android framework for the different types of List views available. Basically you define the layout of a list item in xml that corresponds to an object in the list. You then feed the adapter a list of objects and the layout you want to represent those objects. The adapter takes each object, plugs the appropriate information into the list item view, and then loads it into your parent list. Check out https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView for a thorough explanation of these interactions and their implementation.

Comment: I have the adapter code already there. The problem is the source for the adapter. If I only define a layout xml for each title entry, there would be no way for the adapter to find the names for list entries. Because it can't read inside the xml elements (except if you try to parse the xmls in the app which I decided not to do for now).

Answer (score 0):

The design I finally decided to use is as follows:
The app has a list of articles/contents/entries which you can choose and read. We have one root activity and one title-view. In the root activity I created a class to keep info about each article which for now is two resource IDs. One ID is for the layout to be shown in title-view activity and the other is for the string resource of the article. I have also overridden toString() to return the article title string. It was critical for the ArrayAdapter to be able to display the article name in the list.
Now every time I add an article I should:

1. Give it a name in the string resources.
2. Create a layout for it.
3. Add it to the articles array in the App by "new"ing (instantiating) a ArticleClass.

When the user selects an article I create an intent and add the two resource IDS to its extras.

Here is the code:

```
package com.siavoshkc.x;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.TintResources;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class RootActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView rootListView;
    class TitleEntry{
        int layout_resID;
        int str_resID;
        TitleEntry(int name, int ID){
            layout_resID= name;
            str_resID=ID;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){

            return getResources().getString(str_resID);
        }

    }

    final TitleEntry[] entry_items = {new TitleEntry(R.layout.title_data_input, R.string.TITLE_DATA_INPUT)};
    RootActivity t = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_root);

        ArrayAdapter<?> rootListArrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<TitleEntry>(getApplication(),R.layout.list_text_view,R.id.list_view_text_element, entry_items);

        rootListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rootListView);
        rootListView.setAdapter(rootListArrAdapter);

        rootListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent toViewTitle = new Intent(t, EntryView.class);
                //toViewTitle.putExtra(getString(R.string.TITLE_NO), position);
                toViewTitle.putExtra(getString(R.string.TITLE_LAYOUT_ID), entry_items[position].layout_resID);
                toViewTitle.putExtra(getString(R.string.TITLE_STRING_ID), entry_items[position].str_resID);
                startActivity(toViewTitle);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the EntryView activity:

```
package com.siavoshkc.x;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class EntryView extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //RootActivity root = (RootActivity) getParent();
        //RootActivity.TitleEntry[] entry_list=root.GetEntryList();
        //int iNo = intent.getIntExtra(getString(R.string.TITLE_NO), -1);
        int strID = intent.getIntExtra(getString(R.string.TITLE_STRING_ID), -1);
        int layoutID = intent.getIntExtra(getString(R.string.TITLE_LAYOUT_ID), -1);
        setTitle(strID);
        setContentView(layoutID);
    }
}
```